# Where do I fill an array for a datatable to display on render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

I am filling a datatable to display on my webpage. It only renders when I interact with the sort button. Where should I fill this array for use in a datatable such that it happens before the rendering?

```
export function MyComponent() {
const columns = [
    {
        name: 'Player',
        selector: row => row.Player,
        sortable: true,
    },
    
];

const [teamArray, setTeamArray] = useState([])
const [managerTeamList, setTeamList] = useState([])
const [bootstrapData, setBootstrapData] = useState([])
var managersteam = [];

useEffect(() => {
    
    getBootstrap().then(bootstrap => {
        setBootstrapData(bootstrap.elements)
    })

    getManagersTeam(27356,28).then(data => {
        setTeamList(data.picks)
    }) 


    for (var i in managerTeamList) {
        for (var j in bootstrapData) {
            if (managerTeamList[i].element == bootstrapData[j].id) {
                managersteam.push({
                    "Player" : bootstrapData[j].second_name
                })
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    setTeamArray(managersteam)
    
}, []);

return (
<DataTable columns={columns} data={teamArray}/>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please know that the api requests are asynchronous - `getBootstrap` and `getManagersTeam` - so they are empty when you try to loop through the data.

You can use async/await or just update the teamArray when the promises are solved.

You can use the below code:

```js
export function MyComponent() {
  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Player",
      selector: (row) => row.Player,
      sortable: true,
    },
  ];

  const [teamArray, setTeamArray] = useState([]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    var managersteam = [];
    const [bootstrap, data] = await Promise.all([
      getBootstrap(),
      getManagersTeam(27356, 28)
    ]);

    for (var i in data.picks) {
      for (var j in bootstrap.elements) {
        if (data.picks[i].element == bootstrap.elements[j].id) {
          managersteam.push({
            Player: bootstrap.elements[j].second_name,
          });
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    setTeamArray(managersteam);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();    
  }, []);

  return <DataTable columns={columns} data={teamArray} />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand my issue now so that will help me in the future.